# Can't connect to database in JReport

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am using JReport 9.1 on Windows 7 and when I try to run my report, I get this error:

> Report Engine : Query execution error. Details: Error in connecting to
>   jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1521:db_name, Could not initialize
>   class oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory Ensure that the table names, 
>   column names and connection are valid and that the JDBC driver can be
>   loaded from the class path.

The Oracle Databse is 11.2.0.3. I have the ojdbc6dms_g.jar file in my `CLASSPATH`. I have JRE6 and JDK1.6 installed. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ojdbc6.jar` instead of `ojdbc6dms_g.jar`. And the JDBC driver class is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`. It looks like either your Oracle DMS has a problem or the CLASSPATH has an issue.

Comment: I downloaded the ojdbc6.jar file. I put the file in my `\JReport\Designer\lib` directory. I modified `JReport.bat` to include `%REPORTHOME%\lib\ojdbc6.jar;` in my `CLASSPATH`. I still get the same error. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.